# Camel - Connect to ftps and download file on local filesystem

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

I have to build a simple route that download a file from an ftps server to my filesystem with camel so I'm doing the following:

```
from("ftps://esbftp@test.net/test?delay=30000&password=******&fileName=testFile.txt")
.to("file:/mydir/testtest")
```

in the log I dont see any error and the route seems to be correctly initialized (and I'm sure the file is there :)):

```
18:58:13,947 | INFO  | xtenderThread-24 | OsgiSpringCamelContext           | ?                                   ? | 89 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.8.0.fuse-06-11 | Route: FTPTestRoute
 started and consuming from: Endpoint[ftps://esbftp@test.net/test?delay=30000&password=******]
```

this is the setup i have on filezilla to connect to the ftps server and it is working

[image]

If I try to connect to a normal ftp server then the route works perfectly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I was missing 2 parameters

```
&passiveMode=true&binary=true
```

Those parameters are set automatically on filezilla while in camel I had to force them